# Is it possible to rename each file in a folder with a different name using powershell or a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I've tried looking this up but have got nowhere so far and I'm on a time limit.
Let's say I have three files that have similar clones in multiple folders:

```
(folder1)
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png

(folder2)
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
```

I want to rename these using cmd prompt, powershell, or using a .bat to:

```
(folder1)
B-Sign.png
B-Gauge.png
B-Cup.png

(folder2)
G-Sign.png
G-Gauge.png
G-Cup.png
```

I intend to run the commands for each folder as only the front of the name is different. I want something simple.

```
rename-item *.png B-Sign.png
rename-item *.png B-Gauge.png
```

When it needs a different prefix I would just find and replace the prefix with the new one using ctrl+H in notepad.

Problem is I can't figure out, in any of these, how to automatically cycle to the next file in the folder instead of changing all of the files' names at once. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's very easy in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\Folder1" |
Rename-Item -NewName { "B-" + $_.Name }
```

The new name is a result of an Expression that `Rename-Item` knows to evaluate.  Because the information is sent down the pipeline the `Rename-Item` command is run once per file, resulting in names like your example.

Also you can use the filter parameter as you described with either of the below:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\Folder1\*.png" |
Rename-Item -NewName { "B-" + $_.Name }
```

I prefer to filter using the `-Filter` parameter:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\Folder1" -Filter *.png |
Rename-Item -NewName { "B-" + $_.Name }
```

You can store the folder in a variable too:

```
$Folder = "C:\temp\Folder1"

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.png |
Rename-Item -NewName { "B-" + $_.Name }
```

**Update:**

Per comments here's an example to correlate a list of prefixes with the renames you want to do:

```
$Prefix = 'B-'

$NewNames =
@(
    'Sign'
    'Guage'
    'Cup'
)

# If New names are stored ina file simply do:
# $NewNames = Get-Content <FilePath>

$Folder = "C:\temp\Test_10-30-20"

$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.png

For( $i = 0; $i -lt $Files.Count; ++$i )
{
    $CurrentFile = $Files[$i]
    $NewName = $Prefix + $NewNames[$i] + $CurrentFile.Extension
        
    Rename-Item $CurrentFile.FullName -NewName $NewName
}
```

Comment: Each file in each folder is similar and can be named in order, from first to last, the same. The issue is there are 67 items per folder and I have carpal tunnel so I intend to type each name once in a notepad within a powershell command and paste it into powershell for each folder. Does this script rename each file in a way where I can go to the next file I want to rename?

Comment: Q: Do you have a fixed number of prefixes, meaning names before the extension.  If I sort the 67 files then file 1 should be named after newname 1.  It's very easy to correlate but it would look different than above.

Comment: Yes I have a fixed number of prefixes. About 9 in total only reaching 2 characters at most. The script works but only for the first item, how would I repeat it for the next 66 without naming them the same thing?

Comment: Added a new example, but if you have 9 prefixes sign, gauge, cup etc... how do you decide which of the 67 get which prefix?  I may delete this answer and ask you to clarify your question.  All can be done but you have to be more clear.

Comment: Each picture I just name after something, I have everything in separate folders sorted by color. The prefix in this case is B- or Blue. B-Gauge is Blue Gauge because the gauge is the color blue. This script you sent works perfectly!!